# How to open an Outlook email template with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to open an Outlook 2010 email template with Excel.  I get the following error:

> "Run-time error '-2147287038 (80030002)':
> Cannot open file:
> C:\My\Path\MyTemplate.oft. The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program.  Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click Properties to check your permissions for the folder."

The file exists (in the right place), I checked permissions (as far as I know how), and the file is not open.

```vb
Sub Mail_experiment()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.mailitem
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\My\Path\MyTemplate.oft")
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "myEmail@aol.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is my Subject line"
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my system.  If the file doesn't exist, I get a run-time error 42. (File name or class name not found during Automation operation).  I can actually open the template manually while the code is running with no errors. What happens when you browse to your template file "C:\My\Path\MyTemplate.oft" and try to open it manually?

Comment: I can open it manually.  I just can't do it with VBA.  I've tried it with Outlook open, and with Outlook closed.  I can send NEW emails using code.  I just can't open the template.

Comment: Kevin, I forgot to show my appreciation for your efforts.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, anyone reading this will have to understand that I am a novice.  I tried my code on a different computer and it worked.  I went back and changed the file name of my template, as the previous name was in all capitals (shouldn't matter, right?).  I got a message about needing to be an administrator to do this, which I thought was strange since this is my personal home computer.  However, when I clicked "continue" it went ahead and changed the name.  Now it works.  Perhaps some of you know what happened here; I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

"I tried my code on a different computer and it worked. I went back and changed the file name of my template, as the previous name was in all capitals (shouldn't matter, right?). I got a message about needing to be an administrator to do this, which I thought was strange since this is my personal home computer. However, when I clicked "continue" it went ahead and changed the name. Now it works. –  [David Elphee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2146854/david-elphee) Sep 14 '14 at 13:23"

Comment: Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.