# Open Outlook Mail .msg file using VBA from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to **open .msg files from a specified directory using VBA** but I keep getting a runtime error.

The code i have:

```
Sub bla()
    Dim objOL As Object
    Dim Msg As Object
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    inPath = "C:\Users\SiliconPlus\Desktop\Si+ Contact Lists\Contact_Si+"
    thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")
    Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(thisFile)
    ' now use msg to get at the email parts
    MsgBox Msg.Subject
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the runtime error:

> Run-time error '-2147287038 (80030002)':
>
> Cannot open file: AUTO Andy Low Yong Cheng is out of the office (returning 22 09 2014).msg.
>
> The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program. Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click properties to check your permissions for the folder.

Comment: Just reedited and posted the runtime error thx

Comment: Have you actually debugged the code to see what the value of `thisFile` is before continuing?

Comment: How do i debug thisfile can u teach me

Comment: Click in the grey vertical bar on the left of the code, it'll highlight the line on which the exection will enter debug mode. Then place your mouse on the variable that you wish to see! ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open an outlook .msg file from my harddrive that is NOT in outlook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383290/how-do-i-open-an-outlook-msg-file-from-my-harddrive-that-is-not-in-outlook)

Answer (score 5):

Kenneth Li You didn't had the full path when opening the file. Try this:

```
Sub bla_OK()
Dim objOL As Object
Dim Msg As Object
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
inPath = "C:\Users\SiliconPlus\Desktop\Si+ Contact Lists\Contact_Si+"
thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")
'Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(thisFile)
Set Msg = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem(inPath & "\" & thisFile)
' now use msg to get at the email parts
MsgBox Msg.Subject
Set objOL = Nothing
Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you get an error, try the Late Biding** (`Dim Msg As Object`) right under the `MsgBox` (need to be uncommented) :

```
Sub Kenneth_Li()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Msgbox "If you get an error, try the Late Biding right under this (need to be uncommented)"
    'Dim objOL As Object
    'Dim Msg As Object

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    inPath = "C:\Users\SiliconPlus\Desktop\Si+ Contact Lists\Contact_Si+"

    thisFile = LCase(Dir(inPath & "\*.msg"))
    Do While thisFile <> ""

        'Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(thisFile)
        'Or
        'Set Msg = objOL.OpenSharedItem(thisFile)
        'Set Msg = GetNameSpace("MAPI").OpenSharedItem(thisFile)

        'Eventually with Shell command (here for notepad)
        'Shell "notepad " & thisFile
        Set Msg = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem(thisFile)


        Msg.display

        MsgBox Msg.Subject
        thisFile = Dir
    Loop


    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or you can find a nice VB solution there : http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/551148-open-msg-file-using-visual-basic-applications.html#post2721847

And here for more details on `Shell` method : http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/27776-how-open-msg-file-vbulletin.html#post138411

Comment: thx alot R3uk. im currently not able to access outlook library as i am on excel 2007 and it does not contain this library in the references section in vba

Comment: Oh yes of course you can on Office 2007, just Search for `Microsoft Outlook` in the References and if it's not enough : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630378/i-need-to-code-for-the-correct-reference-to-ms-outlook-from-excel

Comment: im still getting an error Cannot open file: AUTO Andy Low Yong Cheng is out of the office (returning 22 09 2014).msg.

The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program. Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click properties to check your permissions for the folder. @R3uK it detects the file but its not able to open it.

Comment: Try to rename your file without capitals and retry the code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829685/trying-to-open-an-outlook-email-template-with-excel-vba
If this works, rename it with capitals and change code, to include `thisFile = LCase(Dir(inPath & "\*.msg"))` instead of `thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")`

Comment: Not working i still get the same error. It just wouldnt open the outlook template from excel.

Comment: When i use OpenSharedItem instead it gives a run-time error 438 Object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: Ok, give it a try now, I think it might be because it is supposed to be used with a NameSpace Object

Comment: Now im getting this same error. Cannot open file: AUTO Andy Low Yong Cheng is out of the office (returning 22 09 2014).msg. The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program. Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click properties to check your permissions for the folder.

Comment: has it got anything to do with permissions?

Comment: Maybe, but as it is on your local disk, I think there is something else. See the edited answer (added `.Session` and other solution to open) and let me know!

Comment: same error man. its still telling me that the file may not exist or i need permission to open or it may be open in another program etcetc. this is really sad.

Comment: Ok, so take a look at `Shell` or VB methods that I linked, you might be able to make it work! ;)

Comment: I was able to successfully modify this code to use this for my application. However, my code will be used by multiple users who may have different references, so I used Late Binding instead: `Dim objOL As Object` & `Dim Msg As Object`. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @TheEngineer : Glad this old post was useful!

Comment: @KennethLi : Can you test Late Binding too?

Comment: @R3uK I've tried using both binding but is not working, Is there any way to surpass this? Thanks.

Comment: @ramj : Post the link to your question (with your code and error) here, I'll take a look! ;)

Comment: @R3uK I have same issue with Kenneth Li. Anyways, I've already found some heads up and I've just forgot the link :) Thank you anyway .. :)

Comment: @Sauron : How about asking a question or at the very least, try to be a bit more descriptive, rather than just "not working" or downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to run the file programmatically (in VBA use the `Shell` command). It will be opened in Outlook where you can get an active inspector window with the item opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub GetMSG()
' True includes subfolders
' False to check only listed folder
   ListFilesInFolder "C:\Users\lengkgan\Desktop\Testing", True
End Sub


Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
    Dim strFile, strFileType, strAttach As String
    Dim openMsg As MailItem

Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFolderpath As String

'where to save attachments
strFolderpath = "C:\Users\lengkgan\Desktop\Testing"

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files

    strFile = FileItem.Name

' This code looks at the last 4 characters in a filename
' If we wanted more than .msg, we'd use Case Select statement
strFileType = LCase$(Right$(strFile, 4))
  If strFileType = ".msg" Then
    Debug.Print FileItem.Path

Set openMsg = Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileItem.Path)
openMsg.Display
    'do whatever

Set objAttachments = openMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    ' Get the file name.
    strAttach = objAttachments.Item(i).Filename

    ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
    strAttach = strFolderpath & strAttach

    ' Save the attachment as a file.
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strAttach

    Next i
    End If
  openMsg.Close olDiscard

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set openMsg = Nothing

' end do whatever
      End If
    Next FileItem
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
      Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edited : How to add the reference 
Click Tools > Reference.
Check the needed reference
[image]

Comment: i get a Compile error:

User-defined type not defined with FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject highlighted, do i need to import anything/libraries etc.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you need add 2 reference : Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library and Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: Click the Tools > References ... at VBA Editor there. I added the snap shot for you to refer.

Comment: @keongkenshih Why use a FSO (`Dir` is far lighter) and save all the attachments, when it wasn't asked?

Comment: i only have Microsoft excel 12.0 object library, and Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library. Where do i download Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library? Sorry ><

Comment: I am using Excel 2013, perhaps you could try to include that reference to check whether it could work or not. By right, it should not be a problem.

Comment: @R3uK I just gave the example that FSO could work on that, of course Dir is far lighter.

Comment: @KennethLi could i know did your problem solve after you add the reference?

Comment: im currently on excel 2007 and i couldnt find that reference microsoft outlook 15.0 object library in the references section. is there a place where i can download it or implement it into my my 2007

Comment: @KennethLi : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630378/i-need-to-code-for-the-correct-reference-to-ms-outlook-from-excel

Comment: Perhaps you need using late binding method :http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/396267-microsoft-outlook-12-0-object-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check follow code and can modify your code

```
Sub CreateFromTemplate() 
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\temp\*.msg") 
MyItem.Display 
End Sub
```